# Magento - countrycode friendly URL's

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

I'm trying to change magento url's for the store switcher. Currently in Magento when you have multi store views for a different country code it shows like: myurl.com/?**_store=french&**_from_store=default

Does anyone know if it's possible to change it so that it shows myurl.com/fr. This would need doing for all different language types using the country code.

Thanks for any help you can offer. 
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can find your solution to manage like as above you want

http://magento-rohan.blogspot.in/2012/10/magento-managing-multiple-website-stores.html

you will do this easily using above link also for video

[www.magentocommerce.com/magento-on-the-fly/multiple-sites/](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-on-the-fly/multiple-sites/)

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: welcome @MartynHill, if my answer will useful to you, dont forget to vote up and accept it, so some one has some issue in future so they can utilize it.

Comment: Create the new folder and copied index.php to the new folder, created the category and added the new site / stores, but when I try and access the store via the backend(system->config->storeview) I get a 404 error, have you ever had this bug. The version I'm running is magento is 1.7

Comment: Was an import sql issue with id's, corrected and worked thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're one configuration setting away. Just go into System > Configuration > Web > URL Options and set 'Add Store Code to URLs' to 'Yes'.